Elliptic curve in finite field
I'm working with an elliptic curve over a finite field where the curve has prime order. This means that every point on the curve can serve as a generator. My question is: Is there a way to map one group of this curve to another group? If so, what methods or approaches could be used to construct such a mapping? I mean a map from a curve to it self!?

Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that $E(\mathbb{F}_p)=\langle P\rangle$ for some point $P$? But if this is the case there's only one subgroup for each divisor of  $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$

E:y
2
=x
3
+15 over the finite field
19
​
. This curve has a prime order of 19, meaning that any point on the curve can act as a generator.
Given two generators
(
,
)
and
(
,
)
, is there a way to define a map between the two, such that it maps
to
,
2
to
2
, and so on for higher multiples? What approaches can be used to construct such a map?

With your recent comment, I don't see where the "subgroups" in your original question appear.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If the curve has prime order, it has no (non-trivial) subgroups, making the question moot. Exactly what do you mean?

I mean possible maps from an Elliptic curve to itself

In the situation where the group of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points is cyclic, i.e.
$$
E(\mathbb{F}_p)=\langle Q\rangle
$$
for some point $Q$ every other generator is $aQ$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathrm{GCD}(a,n)=1$ where $n=|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$.
This follows at once from the theory of cyclic groups.
If moreover $n=q$ is prime then all $a$ not divisible by $q$ will do.
Finally, note that the "multiplication by $a$" map
$$
E\longrightarrow E, \qquad P\mapsto aP
$$
is algebraic (it is an isogeny).

So, to address the OP's clarification in the comments, as I understand it: if $Q= aP$, for some $a$, then $$kP\mapsto akP=kaP=kQ$$ is algebraic.

If we didn't know the value of a, then what we can do?
